# Tabbable input type="file" Without Text Box Being Tabbable

Tags: file-upload, input, triggers, focus

I have an input element of type 'file':

```
<input type="file">
```

and it currently uses jQuery's fileUpload Plugin (version 5.8.1).

I have some css that hides the text box of the file input, exposing only the button (I have no need for the textbox).

I desire the functionality to:

1. click the input button to open the upload dialog...
2. have the input button tabbable (focused) so that I may open the upload dialog that way too

Here is my problem:

If I make my input tabbable, then I also make the textbox tabbable (which I do not want since it's not even visible).

I have looked up the possibility of creating a button which, when clicked, will trigger the click event of the input to upload a file; however, I have read that this may be a security breach and is not supported on many browsers.

Is there a way that I may make the input tabbable (but only to the button), or is there some other way to trigger the click event on a input of type file?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.